# How to find which file is serving ads in my application?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ads, malware

Ok, somehow I am serving ads in my NodeJS / AngularJS application, but I haven't include this myself.

There's some package or included link sending ads to the client, but the ads are not visible, and the **adserve url changes with every request**. (The url that can be seen in the screenshot below)

How do I find out which place in my application serves these ads?

PS: I am sure this doesn't come from my local dev pc, my other collegues have this issue as well.

[image]

Comment: Are you using any suspicious CDN ?
I'd also check the network tab of the dev console to see if it can determine which file is issuing this request.

Comment: I believe I have found the script responsible... but how can I verify it without blaming the creator (if im wrong) ?

Comment: I have verified the script i menitoned above is responsible for these ads. I contact the author now and update this post once I get an answer from them

Comment: Good to know ! I'm only assuming, but It may not be the authors' intention to display ads. Maybe malicious peoples are redistributing their script with ads. Either case, you should contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "adserver" in my project turns out to be a tracking / analytics beacon included by the [Realtime.co](http://www.realtime.co) framework.

Thankfully, the author responded to my email very quickly, and they also provide a [beacon-free version](http://messaging-public.realtime.co/js/2.1.0/ortc-nobeacon.js) of their framework. So problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick trick may be to search for the url in every files of your repository. If you use a cdn to load your librairies, try to look inside also (you can do that directly in chrome dev tool with ctrl/cmd f in the sources tab). 
Hope it will help !